# React Router DOM: Unable to change route to /view from /view/subview

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am able to navigate from `/about` to `/portfolio`. I can go to `/portfolio/subItem1` or `/portfolio/subItem2`. I can click the back button to return to `/portfolio`. But I can not click the nav link while on any subitem route to go to `/portfolio`.

I suspect some sort of routing error, possibly between the top level router on `App` and the subrouter on the `Portfolio` component. I'm using react-router-dom 5.2.0.

```
// top level component

const bodyViews: Record<string, ComponentData> = {
  cover: { name: "Home", slug: '/', component: Cover },
  portfolio: { name: "Portfolio", slug: "/portfolio", component: Portfolio },
  about: { name: "About", slug: '/about', component: About },
  contact: { name: "Contact", slug: '/contact', component: Contact }
}


function App() {
  return (
    <OutermostStyleContainer>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Nav bodyViews={bodyViews} />

        <main>
          <Switch>
              <Route path='/about'><About /></Route>
              <Route path='/contact'><Contact /></Route>
              <Route path='/portfolio'><Portfolio /></Route>
              <Route path='/' exact><Cover /></Route>
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </OutermostStyleContainer>
  );
}


// reduced portfolio component
interface PropsShape {}

export default (props: PropsShape) => {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <section>
        <Switch>
          {/* Routes to sub-views */}
          <Route path={`${useRouteMatch().path}/call-track-voipms`}>
            <CallTrackVoipMs GithubLogo={GithubLogo} />
          </Route>
          {/* Nav links on category view */}
          <ItemPreviews 
            previewData={typeCheckedNavigationData} 
            portfolioRoute={useRouteMatch().url} 
          />
        </Switch>
      </section>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

// full Nav component
export default (props: PropsShape) => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <div>
        <LinkList jsxData={props.bodyViews} />
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

// LinkList. NavList is a styled HOC of <ul>
export default (props: { jsxData: Record<string, ComponentData> }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <NavList>
        { Object.values(props.jsxData).map((nameAndSlug: ComponentData) => (
          <SingleLinkListItem linkData={nameAndSlug} />
        )) }
      </NavList>
    </section>
  )
} 

// SingleListItem. StyledLink is as the name suggests
export default (props: { linkData: ComponentData }): JSX.Element => {
  return (
  <li>
    <StyledLink to={props.linkData.slug}>{props.linkData.name}</StyledLink>
  </li>
  )
}
```

Does anyone see what is causing the routing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not wrap the `Portfolio` component with `<BrowserRouter>`.
You should only wrap the top of the component with `<BrowserRouter>`.
And you can only wrap your child components with `<Switch>`.

```
// reduced portfolio component
interface PropsShape {}

export default (props: PropsShape) => {

  return (
      <section>
        <Switch>
          {/* Routes to sub-views */}
          <Route path={`${useRouteMatch().path}/call-track-voipms`}>
            <CallTrackVoipMs GithubLogo={GithubLogo} />
          </Route>
          {/* Nav links on category view */}
          <ItemPreviews 
            previewData={typeCheckedNavigationData} 
            portfolioRoute={useRouteMatch().url} 
          />
        </Switch>
      </section>
  )
}
```